Media3 exoplayer custom player view control layout pause and play buttons not working
I just migrated from exxoplayer2 to media3 and I am facing some issue with the custom player control view buttons (eco_play and exo_pause)
I have a player view
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
 android:id="@+id/player_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:visibility="visible"
 app:controller_layout_id="@layout/player_control_view" />

And in my player_control_view layout I have added
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlRack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            style="@style/PlayerControlButtonBaseStyle.RewButton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/PlayerControlButtonBaseStyle.PlayButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/player_control_play_pause_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/player_control_play_pause_margin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/PlayerControlButtonBaseStyle.PauseButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/player_control_play_pause_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/player_control_play_pause_margin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            style="@style/PlayerControlButtonBaseStyle.FfwdButton" />
</LinearLayout>

Now if I try to run the app after the migration the play and pause buttons are not functioning as expected and its showing up both play and pause on my layer side by side.
I tried giving a touchEvent method for the button it didn't work at all.
I am not really sure what to do here.
Because the exo_play and exo_pause buttons of default exoplayer should come up at one and not 2 separate buttons side by side.
Thank you for all the help

you have to setup logic like clickListener to manage play and pause , to show single button at an time use visibility.

can you show your code? make sure to follow https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer/migration-guide and https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/demos/session

So I followed the migration guide but I did manual migration not with script.
Also I was looking in the code and the previous implementation of custom_player_view also had exo_play and exo_pause button and it worked as one button but after migration is messed up

Okay, here is the formatted code in Markdown:
Problem: Merge play and pause buttons into one button
Steps:
1. Merge the buttons into one using the following code:
<!-- old code -->
<FrameLayout>

  <ImageButton 
    android:id="@id/exo_play"/>

  <ImageButton  
    android:id="@id/exo_pause"/>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- replace with --> 

<FrameLayout>

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@id/exo_play_pause"/>

</FrameLayout>

2. Create a drawables.xml file in values to override the play and pause icons:
<!-- drawables.xml -->

<drawable name="exo_styled_controls_pause">
  @drawable/ic_pause
</drawable>

<drawable name="exo_styled_controls_play">
  @drawable/ic_play
</drawable>  

3. Note:
Do not change the attribute names, only override the icon drawables (ic_pause, ic_play) to customize the play/pause icon style.

Let me know if you have any other questions! Have fun coding.

This issue is specific to merging the play/pause buttons when working with the Media3 library. The native play/pause handling is still not fully resolved in Media3.
However, by following the steps outlined above to merge the buttons and override the icon drawable

Reference link:
https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/398
&
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5372
&
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/afd11de/library/ui/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml#L9
